# How to create preloader for ExtJS 4 application

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, preloader

I would like to add preloader screen in my application to serve to two purposes:

1. To show some progress about the initialization or overall loading of application to user
2. In future to display important notice or new features roll out message while loading is happening.

Comment: Ok, we made one, just google it.
and what is your question ?

Comment: loading of a medium sized app should take about 5-6 seconds, you cant read messages that fast.

Comment: DmitryB, yes 2nd use case is not primary but given I have to load multiple data from different service while loading app. Instead of showing application loading in between i prefer to show loading as we can do in flex.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413337/extjs-4-1-mvc-how-to-apply-loadmask-to-viewport-while-loading/11414925#11414925

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @Sha for sharing the link.

I have also found bit detailed example on how to use preloader
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?230118-Splash-Screen

http://blog.newbridgegreen.com/extjs-4-splash-screen/